# mysql command not found

Tags: mysql, rhel5

I recently installed MySQL on RHEL5. I installed it to /usr/local/mysql

Complete steps for installation are here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-installation.html

```
shell> cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql.server
```

Then I could not start it from /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start command

Now I can stop and start MySQL using the below command

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

To create database here are the first step

```
mysql -u root -h localhost
```

I get command not found from anywhere I run. What should I try?

Comment: Normally, you would just `yum install mysql mysql-server` on a Red Hat machine, but if you did it manually I _think_ that the `mysql` binary now resides in `/usr/local/mysql/bin` which is not in your `$PATH`.  Please check `ls /usr/local/mysql` and see if there's a `bin/` directory.

Comment: If so, it is then a matter of adding it to your path `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`

Comment: This worked for me ^ - super annoying how there is no mention of /usr/local/mysql/bin in the documentation.  Instead they reference the location of other files which is doubly misleading